# Improving performance of Cronbach Alpha code python numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I made some code for calculating Cronbach Alpha that works. But I am not too good using lambda functions. Is there a way to reduce the code and improve efficiency by using lambda instead of the svar() function and getting rid of some of the for loops by using numpy arrays?

```
import numpy as np


def svar(X):
    n = float(len(X))
    svar=(sum([(x-np.mean(X))**2 for x in X]) / n)* n/(n-1.)
    return svar


def CronbachAlpha(itemscores):
    itemvars = [svar(item) for item in itemscores]
    tscores = [0] * len(itemscores[0])
    for item in itemscores:
       for i in range(len(item)):
          tscores[i]+= item[i]
    nitems = len(itemscores)
    #print "total scores=", tscores, 'number of items=', nitems

    Calpha=nitems/(nitems-1.) * (1-sum(itemvars)/ svar(tscores))

    return Calpha

###########Test################
itemscores = [[ 4,14,3,3,23,4,52,3,33,3],
              [ 5,14,4,3,24,5,55,4,15,3]]
print "Cronbach alpha = ", CronbachAlpha(itemscores)
```

Comment: Why would lambdas help here?

Comment: For anyone being extremely puzzled as to why it would return always close to 1.0, you have to mind that here itemscores is n*p, with n (each row) being item (a question), and p (each column) being your subject's answer.

If you're using pandas like I am, chances are you have each row being the respondent and each column being the item. So to use this function, you need to transpose the dataframe or modify the function.

Also mind that in Python 2.7, you need to import division from future or enclose the denominators in float()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def CronbachAlpha(itemscores):
    itemscores = numpy.asarray(itemscores)
    itemvars = itemscores.var(axis=1, ddof=1)
    tscores = itemscores.sum(axis=0)
    nitems = len(itemscores)

    return nitems / (nitems-1.) * (1 - itemvars.sum() / tscores.var(ddof=1))
```

NumPy has a variance function built in. Specifying `ddof=1` uses a denominator of N-1, giving a sample variance. There's also a `sum` builtin.

Comment: Thanks for the share! I pusblished a lib based on your code for this cronbach_alpha at https://github.com/anthropedia/tci-stats. Hopelly I can enrich it later on.

Answer (score 1):

As Julien Marrec mentioned I suggest the following refactoring of the CronbachAlpha:

```
def CronbachAlpha(itemscores):
    # cols are items, rows are observations
    itemscores = np.asarray(itemscores)
    itemvars = itemscores.var(axis=0, ddof=1)
    tscores = itemscores.sum(axis=1)
    nitems = len(itemscores.columns)

    return (nitems / (nitems-1)) * (1 - (itemvars.sum() / tscores.var(ddof=1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as the other answers, just a bit more Pythonic. `X` is a data matrix -- that is, the rows are samples, the columns are items. `X` may be a numpy array or pandas DataFrame.

```
def cronbach_alpha(X):
    num_items = X.shape[1]
    sum_of_item_variances = X.var(axis=0).sum()
    variance_of_sum_of_items = X.sum(axis=1).var()
    return num_items/(num_items - 1)*(1 - sum_of_item_variances/variance_of_sum_of_items)
```

(It's not necessary to specify `ddof`, as the term appears in the denominator and numerator, and cancels.)